# Passing Data between pages in C#

Tags: c#, generics, windows-phone

Hello I am currently trying to pass the data from mt Generic list of pets to a "Profile" page and I am using the OnNavigatedTo method to do this, the only problem being is that it is only taking the 1st item I want it to pass and is ignoring the rest.

This is where I have created my Generic list, in the App.XAML

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
    {
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Johnny", Age= 2, Breed="Husky", Type= "Dog", Stock = 1, Price = 125, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Husky.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Billy", Age= 1, Breed="Shiba Inu", Type= "Dog", Stock = 1, Price = 250, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Shiba Inu.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Sammy", Age = 8, Breed="Siamese", Type="Cat", Stock = 1, Price = 15, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Siamese Cat.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Molly", Age = 6, Breed="Norwegian", Type="Cat", Stock = 1, Price = 30, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/NorwegianForestCat.jpeg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Nemo", Age = 3, Breed="Clown Fish", Type="Fish", Stock = 1, Price = 10, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/clown Fish.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Dory", Age = 1, Breed="Palette SurgeonFish", Type="Fish", Price = 75, Stock = 1, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Palette Surgeonfish.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop{Name = "Keith", Age = 4, Breed="Bearded Dragon", Type="Lizard", Stock = 1, Price = 750, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Bearded Dragon.jpg"});
            myshop.Add(new Shop {Name = "Oisin", Age = 12, Breed = "Gecko", Type = "Lizard", Stock = 1, Price = 90, Photo = "/Assignment 1;component/Images/Gecko.jpg" });
    }
```

I then have started the passing of the data on the selection of an item in my generic list

```
private void list_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Shop selectedPet = list.SelectedItem as Shop;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Profile.xaml?" + "name=" + selectedPet.Name + " & " + "age=" + selectedPet.Age + " & " + "breed=" + selectedPet.Breed + " & " + "price=" + selectedPet.Price, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

    }
```

Finally this is where it SHOULD (I believe) be loading the data into the textblocks I have created on the APP page (see pic below)

```
public partial class Profile : PhoneApplicationPage
{
    App thisApp = Application.Current as App;

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string name;
        string age;
        string breed;
        string price;

        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
        {
            nameTxtBlock.Text = name;
        }
        else if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("age", out age))
        {
            ageTxtBlock.Text = age;
        }
        else if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("breed", out breed))
        {
            breedTxtBlock.Text = breed;
        }
        else if(NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("price", out price))
        {
            priceTxtBlock.Text = price;
        }   
    }
```

So my question is, if any of you guys could tell me why it won't pass all the data to the new page and a possible fix it would be much appreciated. Also if you need to see any more parts of my code just comment telling me what you require and I will add it in then.

Thanks in advance, Jason

////Pics\\
This is where i will select the animal >>> http://gyazo.com/4e39a228aca8ceff1cb83f54b7ba9d89

This is showing that it only passes the first piece of data (Name) >> http://gyazo.com/832f262b46191e5e0992f02533a6b632

Comment: Links to the pictures are broken. Please upload them to StackOverflow or another reliable image host.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass only the identifier to your page. Let's say the Name is unique and is the identifier of your objects.

To navigate :

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Profile.xaml?" + "name=" + selectedPet.Name, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Then in Profile page :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    string name;
    Shop currentShop;

    if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
    {
        //Use your repository to fetch the object
        currentShop = App.myshop.First(s => s.Name == name);
        //Then initialize with fetched object...
    }
```

You should avoid long data in urls

The issue you have (data not present in `NavigationContext.QueryString`) might occur because you dont escape values. Try [Uri.Escapedatastring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/vstudio/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) :

```
    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Profile.xaml?" + "name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(selectedPet.Name) + " & " + "age=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(selectedPet.Age) + " & " + "breed=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(selectedPet.Breed) + " & " + "price=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(selectedPet.Price), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

Comment: This is giving an error, the Uri.EscapeDataString(selectedPet.Name) works (as in doesn't give an error) but the 2 other Uri.EscapeDataString's give underlined errors saying "The best overloaded method match for 'System.Uri.EscapeDataString(string)' has some invalid arguements.

Comment: @JasonL95 Add .ToString() when required : selectedPet.Age.ToString()

Comment: It now crashes when i click the selected pet. I used a breakpoint and this is where the error seems to stem from, any help?    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            Shop currentShop;

            if (NavigationContext.QueryString.TryGetValue("name", out name))
            {
                //Use your repository to fetch the object
                currentShop = thisApp.myshop.First(s => s.Name == name);
                //Then initialize with fetched object...
            }

Answer (score 0):

Querystrings shall not be used to pass the complete item as query string only passes a single variable.

You can store a user defined object in IsolatedStorage Application settings

save your object Just before Doing the navgation on selectionchenged event

```
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] = selectedPet;
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
```

and on Profile.xaml page OnNavigatedTo Handler Just get the object back

```
 if (IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("State") == true)
 {
 var object= IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["State"] as Shop;
 //Remove the state now
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Remove("State");
 IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Save();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Aman Pointed out the best way to be doing what you are attempting to do is with IsolatedStorage. I don't agree however how he suggested. `IsolatedStorageSettings` is meant for app settings. Using it to pass objects is a hack.

My suggestion is that you `serialize` your object to `IsolatedStorage`, then pass the file name so you can `deserialize` it on the other side.

There is a DLL called `EZ_Iso` that lets you `serialize` and `deserialize` with a single method call. Super efficient.

[Get EZ_Iso.dll and Documentation Here](http://anthonyrussell.info/postpage.php?name=2)

An example for your case would be

To serialize it

```
EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.SaveFile("SelectedPet",YourSelectedPetObject);
```

Then to deserialize it

```
   Shop yourPet = (Shop)EZ_Iso.IsolatedStorageAccess.GetFile("SelectedPet",typeof(Shop));
```

Doing this will clean up a TON of your code. You wont be required to have disgusting globals in the app.cs file. Adopting an architecture like this is much more in line with MVVM and also makes it easier to databind the results that come out of the serialization.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass data between pages by four ways which is clearly explained in following post

http://nishantcop.blogspot.in/2011/08/passing-data-between-pages-in-windows.html